# I am having trouble setting up a personal Murmur server

Tags: networking, debian, virtual-machine, timeout, mumble

I recently set up a small Debian VM (no GUI, command line only) and installed `mumble-server` on it. I went into `dpkg-reconfigure` and set the following:

- Autostart : Yes
- High Priority : Yes
- Super User : [[root pswd]]

After that, I ran `ip addr show` and got the IP address of the VM. I also ran `sudo nano /etc/mumble-server.ini` and changed the base channel name and welcome message.

After all of this, I installed the Mumble client on my computer (Windows 10 Pro) and went through the Audio Tuning Wizard. I then input the label, IP address, left the port alone, and input "superuser" as the username (note, there was no password field for *any* server). I could not login. It simply kept saying "Connecting...", then telling me that the connection timed out.

I can connect to any other server in seconds, it's just my local server that is not connecting.

Comment: How is your VM connected to the network, what hypervisor are you using?  Can you ping the VM from your Windows computer?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox. The VM is connected through the default method that VirtualBox uses, I'm not sure what method that would be, though. There were two IP addresses listed when I ran `ip addr show`, and pinging either of them resulted in 100% loss (requests timed out).

Comment: Also, to help clarify the network deal, my desktop is connected via a wireless USB adapter